# dividing a rectangle shaped surface into small equal rectangles with gaps in between

Tags: matlab, rectangles, surface

I would like to write a program that can help me to divide a certain rectangle surface where I know its dimensions into M (Known) small squares with gaps in between. The dimensions of these small rectangles should be between 0,5 and 5mm and it is the same for the dimensions of the gaps. I wrote a simple code but I m not able to get all the possible configurations and most of the time i got no result.

```
Hrect = 150; Vrect =20;
minSq=1;maxSq=5;%sqaure
minSp=1;maxSp=5;%space
minM=1; maxM=5;%margin
nb_squares=2;
res=[];
c=0;

    for HSQ=minSq:maxSq
     for HSP=minSp:maxSp
      for VSQ=minSq:maxSq
       for VSP= minSp:maxSp
            nb_HSQ=(Hrect/HSQ);

            if(Hrect-nb_HSQ*(HSQ+HSP)>=HSQ)
                nb_HSQ=nb_HSQ+1;
            end
            nb_VSQ=(Vrect/(VSQ+VSP));
           if(Vrect - nb_VSQ*(VSQ+VSP)>=VSQ)
            nb_VSQ=nb_VSQ+1;
        end
if(nb_HSQ*nb_VSQ==nb_squares) c=c+1;
    res(c,1)=VSQ; res(c,2)=HSQ;res(c,3)=HSP;res(c,4)=VSP;res(c,5)=nb_HSQ;res(c,6)=nb_VSQ;
       if(c==4000000) disp('stop here')
       end
end
    end

end
end 
end
res
res
```

Comment: Please [edit] your code with proper formatting.

Comment: It is unclear, is the number `M` (the number of sub squares) fixed at the start, or is it an output of the calculation?

Comment: no the number of subsquares is an input but their dimensions will be an output